# Java object diffs: How to apply diffs to an object

Tags: java, object, graph, compare

I have an object `A'` that contains lists, maps and other collections on **server_1**. Then I send this object to **server_2**.

After that on the **server_1** the object `A'` is changed to state `A''`.

The point is `A''` doesn't have many changes and it's expensive to send whole object `A''` to the **server_2**.

So if I want to update state of the object `A'` on the **server_2** I have to send difference between this objects: `dA = A'' - A'` to the **server_2** and then apply `dA` to the `A'`.

I try to use two libraries for getting `dA`:

- [java-object-diff](https://github.com/SQiShER/java-object-diff)
- [javers](https://github.com/javers/javers)

But now I'm confused how to apply diffs `dA` to the object `A'` on the **server_2**.

Does someone know how to solve this problem or any other libraris for this use case?

EDIT:
Object structure example (this version a little bit simpler than actual object):

```
class Outer {
    SimpleObj val1;
    List<ComplexObj> list;
    Map<String, Map<String, List<OtherComplexObj>> map;
}
```

It seems complicated to check all fields recursively without using any library.

EDIT: There is [a spring-synk library](https://spring.io/blog/2014/10/22/introducing-spring-sync). It designed for case like my own but I have had StackOverflowError while creating a diff for my objects. This problem occurs due to complexity of my object but I cant simplify it for now. Changing jvm params doesn't help. I wonder is it possible to use this library for complex objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used https://github.com/malensek/jbsdiff - this library let me get binary diff of my objects and then apply this diff to binary representation of the object A' on the **server_2**. There is a moment about this solution - if object A' is large it requires big memory allocation and in my case it allocates in Old Generation.

Answer (score 0):

You could send a byte that specifies the field that is to be sent next. Send 0 to specify that the transmission has ended.

```
public void sendDiff(MyClass obj){
    if(!this.field1.equals(obj.field1)){
        send(1) // 1 for field 1
        send(obj.field1)
    }
    if(!this.field2.equals(obj.field2)){
        send(2) // 2 for field 2
        send(obj.field2)
    }
    // et.c for each field
    send(0) // 0 to signify that we have finished sending the changed fields
}
```

You would then get a stream if bytes followed by fields whose values have been changed.

Comment: For now **server_2** send the object `A''` to the **server_2** and replace `A'` and it works. But I want to minimize used traffic due to the object `A''` is large.

Comment: @kali Well if so you could just send a byte (signals which field is being changed) and then send the changed field. This way you only need to send  the fields that have changed.

Comment: It's exactly what I want to do. And I'm searching library which helps me recursively analyze complex object and then apply result to the object on the other server.

Comment: It works if I have a simple object but in my case it's a complex object. 
I edited my question and added simple example of structure of my object.

Comment: @kali It shouldn't be too complex, just use the **equals()** method on each object, as I did in my answer.